# Set of sequences with zero sum density in $l_2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

Let

$M_1 = \{x = (x_1, x_2, ...) \in l_2 : \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} x_k = 0\}$

$M_2 = \{x = (x_1, x_2, ...) \in l_2 : \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{x_k}{k} = 0\}$

Check if these sets are dense in $l_2$.

My attempt is the following:
Let $a=(a_k)$ from $l_2$ where $a_k$ has conditionally convergent series (for an example  $a_k = \frac{\sin k}{k}$).

Let $x\in l_2$, thus $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |x_k|^2 < +\infty$. Therefore there is an $N_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ for any given $\varepsilon <0$ such that $\sum_{k=N_0}^{\infty} |x_k|^2 < \varepsilon$

Let $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |a_k|^2 = S$ then let $b_k = \sqrt{\frac{\varepsilon}{S}}a_k$, then $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |b_k|^2 = \varepsilon$ and is still conditionally convergent.

Let $x = -\sum_{k=1}^{N_0-1} x_k$ then using Riemann theorem about sum of conditionally convergent series there is a sequence $\{k_j\}_{j = 1}^{\infty}$ such that $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} b_{k_j} = x$ .
Then let

$g_n = \begin{cases} 
      x_n, n< N_0\\
      b_{k_{n-N_0+1}}, n\geq N_0
   \end{cases}$

Then $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} g_{k} = x -x = 0$, thus $g = (g_n) \in M_1$

Therefore $||x-g||_{l_2}^2 = \sum_{n= N_0}^{\infty} |b_{k_{n-N_0+1}}- x_n|^2\leq \sum_{n= N_0}^{\infty} |b_{k_{n-N_0+1}}|^2+ |x_n|^2 \leq 2\varepsilon$ thus $M_1$ is dense in $l_2$.

I was thinking that I can somehow rebuild my $b_k$ so they can fit the $M_2$ but I can't really do that since now I would probably need series which is conditionally convergent when every term is divided by $k$ and this is impossible because of comparison test (like if it is from $l_2$ then norm converges then $|a_k|^2<1/k$, thus $|a_k|/k <1/k^{3/2}$ so it converges absolutely). So I expect it to be not dense but can't figure out the way to prove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sequence $x=(\frac 1 k)$ is an elmenet of $\ell^{2}$ and $M_2$ is simply the orthogonal complement $M_2^{\perp}$ of $M_2$. A subspace $M$ is dense iff $M^{\perp}$ is $\{0\}$. In this case $M_2^{\perp}$ is the one dimensional subspace spanned by the vector $x$. Hence $M_2$ is not dense. In particular you can show that $x$ does not belong to the closure of $M_2$.

Comment: Thank you very much! Haven't thought about orthogonal complements.

Answer (score 1):

For $M_1$: consider the linear functional $f(x)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty x_k$ in $\ell_2$, then $M_1=\ker f$. Since $(1,1,1,...)\notin\ell_2$, then $f$ is unbounded. But it's well known that kernel of unbounded linear functional is dense in considering space.

For $M_2$, similar functional is bounded, therefore its kernel is closed, but since it does not coincide with the whole space, it is not dense.

Comment: $f$ is not well-defined, since $x=(1/n)\in\ell_2$ but $f(x)=+\infty$

Comment: Certainly not well defined. It must be defined on a dense subset of $l_2$, say, finite sequences (with zeros, starting from some place). Then it's kernel lies in $M_1$ and by density of functional's domain, $M_1$ is dense.

Comment: Now it makes more sense; thanks! Maybe you should add it to your answer so it's more detailed.